# Problem creating a Table of Contents (with "infinite" height) using HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Basically I want to have two sections with completely independent scrolls:

- A TOC (generated with JS using H1,H2,H3 from the content)
- Content (text and images)

Here's the CSS:

```
#post-content {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 30%;
}
#toc {
  width: 30%;
  position: fixed;
  height: 600px; // this would probably be calculated using the viewport
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

I already have the basic HTML/CSS/JS at this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/pmqa/pen/WNJOPKQ) but I'm unable for some reason to have the TOC scroll to the bottom. Meaning, there are more UL/LI's but they aren't shown.

I'm pretty sure I'm failing at the CSS but I can't get it right.

Any help, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the question itself, preferably as a [MCVE]. Make it as easy as possible for us to help you. Don't make us go off-site to find vital information. In the meantime investigate the `vh` unit (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units)

Answer (score 1):

Change the style for `#toc` to this:

```
#toc {
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;     /* <---- Changed */
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 0;            /* <---- Added   */
}
```

Or if you do not want to show the horizontal scrollbar, adjust `top` as follows

```
#toc {
    width: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;     /* <---- Changed */
    overflow: scroll;
    top: 12px;         /* <---- Added   */
}
```

Comment: That was it! The vh, viewport height. The height had to be the viewport height and not a given set of pixels because the latter would affect also the actual amount of content. Thanks very much!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be close. This is working for me on my large screen but if I reduce the height of the window I run in to issues.

If the height of the window is less than 600px high (the height you've set) then you won't get to see the bottom of the scrollable toc. Try adding `max-height: 100vh` and see if that makes a difference.

That way you set a height of 600px but if the window is shorter, you set the maximum height to the height of the window instead.